# Set div to be relative to body

Tags: html, css

I wan't to to div with class "absolute" to set relative to body, without of divs changing position, is it posible and how.

I can't change for div position because my project is big, and other content will not look good if I do that.

HTML, CSS:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}
.container {
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
}
.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="absolute">
            ABSOLUTE
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I dont understand. Maybe you can use paint and show me how you want it to look?

Comment: Do you mean the width of div should be relative to the width of body?

Comment: if you use relative positioning on a parent element, children position will be relative to it. I think you cannot change that.

Comment: No, I have main container with 960px, a he is center. Inside them a have absolute div, and I want for fotoer that absolute div to be relative to body full width 100%

Comment: @ml92 Try `position: fixed`.

Comment: If you just wants to stretch `background-color` (not content), you can use `:before` or `:after` pseudo elements for this.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman can you explain it on jsfiddle, yes just that I want

Comment: @ml92 Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/36rcvbcu/2/

Comment: @ml92 you are welcome)